# How to control event IBActions in UIButton?

Tags: ios, events, uibutton

I have a game of questions, in my game when a gamer click in a buttom, if the answer is correct it puts green and if the answer is wrong it puts red.
The problem is the user can to touch and move, and with this event he cans to see the color, because it change, but that event no active the function of eveluate if the question is correct. In other words it is a trick for the user, because he can see what is the correct question and no pay lives

How I need control this event?

I think something like this

```
- (IBAction)respuesta1:(id)sender {
if(!IsDrag){
      [self comprueba_respuesta:1];
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you not change your UIButton action to `UIControlEventTouchUpOutside`.

Answer (score 0):

You should link the UIControlEventTouchUpOutside action to UIButton, then the button only will execute IBActions when the user touch up inside button. I think it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers, I meet the solution with yout comments:

In the viewLoad I declare the event TouchDown, because the only I need is to know if the user click the buttom

```
 [respuesta1_btn addTarget:self action:@selector(pulsado1:withEvent: )forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

And them I declare the function

```
- (void)pulsado1: (UIControl *) c withEvent:ev
{
[self comprueba_respuesta:1];
}
```

In my case is not necesary use IBAction, and I do equal for my others UIButtoms
**The user don´t make trick anymore!!**